# How can I save what components are rendered and their state in my app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Lets say I have the following components: `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, `ComponentC` The user of my app can perform actions to fill an array of undefined length with any order of these components. For example: `[ComponentC, ComponentA, ComponentC, ComponentB]` or `[ComponentB, ComponentA]`, etc.
When the user clicks save, I want this data to be stored - the exact arrangement of the array and all the props/states of each component. When the user revisits or reloads the page, I want to populate this array exactly how they saved it. How can I do that?

I was trying to use redux but I'm running into issues because you can't serialize a React component. Does anyone know if this is possible? After I save it, how do I retrieve it and turn it into a renderable React component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components should be pure functions of props and state. With that in mind, you should only need to save the relevant props and state in an array in order to replicate the components. For this you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You could create an array with the following format:

```
const compArr =
[
  {
    name: "ComponentA",
    state: {
             key: "value"
            },
    props: {
             key: "value"
            },
   },
   ...
];
```

Then save it to `localStorage` when the user clicks a button using:

```
localStorage.setItem("components",JSON.stringify(compArr));
```

Load with:

```
const compArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("components"));
```

You would then need to recreate your components by passing them props from the array of objects (`compArr`). Their default states can then be derived from the state property of the objects in the array, or if the state is derived from props (less common), you can set their states on mounting the component with a `useEffect` hook.